# C# Regex to split string by commas that are only before "or"

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to split the following string based on the commas that come before the "or" delimiter and on the "or", but not after. For example

```
Almondmilk, Coconutmilk or Soymilk Select Varieties, Half Gallon
```

becomes

1. **Almondmilk**
2. **Coconutmilk**
3. **Soymilk Select Varieties, Half Gallon**

Comment: Please put your attempt in the question.

Comment: it's unclear. Explain a bit more..

Comment: Can't you just do a regular split on "or" and then split the first result on ","?

Comment: A list of your desires is not a question; can you phrase your question in the form of *a specific question about actual code*?

Comment: Sorry, yes I want to split on the "or" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirement as described:

```
var output = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!or.*),");
```

However, given your sample output it seems you want to split on 'or' as well:

```
var output = Regex.Split(input,
                         "((?<!or.*),)|(or)",
                         RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: @MattBurland I was just updating the answer as you posted - please check now

Comment: Yep, the second regex appears to work. I had almost the same solution (but using a look ahead instead of a look behind) but was missing the `ExplicitCapture` part.

Comment: Thanks @MattBurland, you helped a lot. I did not think of doing that way. Sorry that the question was done badly.

Comment: Thanks @decPL of course you answered the question.